# Why isn't clearRect working on HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ecmascript-6

To put it simply, instead of clearing the canvas and drawing a new shape every time a button is pressed, it just draws over the shape already on canvas and I have no idea. My code is below. the shapes that are created inside the event listeners are just shapes that I pre made in classes that mainly contain rectangles and circles to create more complex shapes and should have nothing to do with the problem I am having.

```
 class CompoundDrawable extends Drawable{
    constructor(context, x = 0, y = 0, fillStyle = "#000", strokeStyle = "transparent", lineWidth = 0, deltas = new Map(), shapes = new Set()){
    super(context, x, y, fillStyle, strokeStyle, lineWidth, deltas);
    this.shapes = shapes;
  } 
draw(){
  super.draw();
  for(const shape of this.shapes){
      shape.draw();
  } 
 super.afterDraw();
  }
}
 // Set that holds all of the objects 
 const canvasObjects = new Set();

document.getElementById("3WheelCar").addEventListener("click",(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newShapeForCanvas = new shape(context,x,y,"green");
    canvasObjects.add(newShapeForCanvas);

    //Calls the function to draw the shapes
    drawShapeToCanvasFunction();
});
// Creates the shapes on button click
document.getElementById("pngCar").addEventListener("click",(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const otherNewShape = new shape(context,x,y,"orange");  
    canvasObjects.add(otherNewShape);

    drawShapeToCanvasFunction();

});

// Draws out the shapes in the set 
function drawShapeToCanvasFunction(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(const canvasObject of canvasObjects){
        canvasObject.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you'd like this question answered.

Comment: @enhzflep just edited, should be easier to understand now.

Comment: No we need to see what you are doing in the drawing part. Blind guess: you forgot to call `beginPath`

Comment: @Kaiido Added the draw method into the code. Iv'e tried `beginPath` but it makes no difference, I'm pretty confident it is not needed.

Comment: I said the drawing part, your draw method is not the drawing part, it calls objects methods. What we need is the context path declarations etc.

Comment: Again, provide a _Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_ if you'd care for the problem to be solved. Currently, you're showing nothing of any interest - any expectation that this will shine light on the broken part of your understanding and implementation is frankly, misplaced.This question could have been answered  nearly 11 hours ago, had you taken the time to make it answerable.